# Dependency is not satisfiable: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.42.0)

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies

Updated my mysql to 5.6 and as a consequence broke my preexisting mysql workbench.

Trying to reinstall the newest mysql workbench, from both the Software Manager and the latest .deb from their downloads page:

`Dependency is not satisfiable: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.42.0)`

I'm running 14.04, and I've found the package here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglibmm-2.4-1c2a

How come I can't install mysql workbench? This dependency seems to be in 14.04.

Comment: Voting to close as unlear because we do not know how MySQL 5.6 was installed, and this is essential to answer the question. (And since the question is over a year old, it is unlikely that OP wil clarify.)

Comment: Honestly I wish I could say. It was so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you got the package you are currently trying to install, you may have the wrong one - your package needs version `(>= 2.42.0)` (i.e. newer than 2.42), but the available trusty version is currently [2.39.93](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglibmm-2.4-1c2a).
You may have accidentally got a package for Utopic or newer *(possibly via a installed [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them))*, as both [Utopic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libglibmm-2.4-1c2a) and [Vivid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libglibmm-2.4-1c2a) have version `2.42.0-1` available.

However, [this package](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1ubu1404-amd64.deb) from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) seems to only need:

> libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1), libc6 (>= 2.14), libcairo2 (>=
>   1.13.0~20140204), libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4), libctemplate2, libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1),
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglib2.0-0
>   (>= 2.35.9),
>  **libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2)**, libgnome-keyring0 (>=
>   2.22.2), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0), libncurses5 (>= 5.5-5~), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0),
>   libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1),
>   libpcre3, libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libpython2.7
>   (>= 2.7), libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.6.0),
>   libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libtinyxml2.6.2, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), libx11-6,
>   libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libzip2 (>= 0.10), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0),
>   python-paramiko

Which should be available in 14.04 - the offical repo version from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mysql-workbench) as well also only needs `libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've upgraded my `mysql-client` to the `mysql-client-5.6` so I can no longer `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench` because `mysql-client-5.6` is not a valid dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve this with detecting dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then update and install new packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It solved my problem with the same description.

Cheers :)

Comment: No reason for -f install if you can install new packages with update && upgrade. It should be ran first.

Comment: Hm, first I did update & upgrade, and then it offered me to install missing dependincies. But if -f install works first then ok.

Answer (score 0):

remove python-connector-mysql mysql-utilities
install mysql-utilites

their is a conflict preventing the proper upgrade path : 
python-connector-mysql -> mysql-connector-python